# Confused about the assignment method in Ruby (defined method with equal sign)

Tags: ruby

I am really confused about the assignment method in Ruby. In the documentation, it says:

> Methods that end with an equals sign indicate an assignment method.
>   For assignment methods, the return value is ignored and the arguments
>   are returned instead.

I know this can be use as setter method in Class. However, I still feel confused about the concept. In the code below:

```
class Foo
  # setter method
  def foo=(x)
    puts "OK: x=#{x}"
  end
end
f = Foo.new
f.foo = 123 # OK: x=123

def a=(value)
  puts "value is #{value}"
end
a = 123     # why there is no output?
p a         # 123, why this only return the argument?
p a = 123   # 123, why this only return the argument?
```

Why the method with equal sign run differently in the Class and outside the class?

Answer (score 4):

> a = 123

In principle, there is ambiguity here. Is it a setter invocation or a local variable assignment? Ruby resolves this by choosing local variable assignment. If you want the method, be explicit.

```
self.a = 123
```

In the other case, there's no ambiguity.

Answer (score 4):

Seeing something like `a = 123`, the interpreter assumes that this is always an assignment operation. However, you can call `self.a = 123`- as this cannot be a proper assignment (variable name cannot include a dot); it will invoke a method you defined.

Note that the same happens inside the class, so it is not a different behaviour:

```
class Foo
  def foo=(x)
    puts "OK: x=#{x}"
  end

  def bar
    foo = 1
  end

  def baz
    self.foo = 1
  end
end
```

Calling `bar` will not print your message, it will just perform an assignment. `baz` will execute your setter method.